# c# Flatten an unknown layer list of lists to a list

Tags: c#, flatten

I want to create a method which can flatten unknown layer list of double[].
`List<double[]> flattenData = flattenMethod(dataSource);`
where data source's type might be
`List<double[]>`
`List<List<double[]>>`
`List<List<List<double[]>>>`
...and so on.

I have tried .Select or .SelectMany but they seems only work for specific layer
and I have no idea what type should I use for input argument type.
Are there a general way to achieve what I want?

Comment: What you are describing is really a tree, so you need to do [Tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work with recursion:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable seq)
{
    foreach (var item in seq)
    {
        if (item is T titem)
        {
            yield return titem;
        }

        if (item is IEnumerable subSeq)
        {
            foreach (var subItem in subSeq.Flatten<T>())
            {
                yield return subItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some test cases:

```
List<double[]> doubleList = new List<double[]>
{
    new double[] { 1, 2, 3 },  new double[] { 4, 5, 6 }
};
 // following array contains 6 doubles:
Double[] doubles = doubleList.Flatten<double>().ToArray();

List<List<double[]>> doubleListList = new List<List<double[]>>()
{
    doubleList, doubleList, doubleList
};
 // following array contains 18 doubles:
doubles = doubleListList.Flatten<double>().ToArray();

List<List<List<double[]>>> doubleListListList = new List<List<List<double[]>>>()
{
    doubleListList, doubleListList, doubleListList
};
 // following array contains 54 doubles:
doubles = doubleListListList.Flatten<double>().ToArray();
```